# Is there a way to achieve center alignment, which dynamically changes to top alignment based on count of items

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In flutter is there any widget which can be used to achieve below layout.
[image: When count of children is less]
When count of children is less
[image: When count of children increases]
When count of children increases
[image: When it count of the children increases and reaches parent size]
When it count of the children increases and reaches parent size

So the widgets are first center aligned and then dynamically align to the top of parent when count of children increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Wrap`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html)
Example from doc

```dart
class _fsState extends State<fs> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Wrap(
                //include alignment if needed
                spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
                runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
                children: <Widget>[
                  Chip(
                    avatar: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900,
                        child: const Text('AH')),
                    label: const Text('Hamilton'),
                  ),
                  Chip(
                    avatar: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900,
                        child: const Text('ML')),
                    label: const Text('Lafayette'),
                  ),
                  Chip(
                    avatar: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900,
                        child: const Text('HM')),
                    label: const Text('Mulligan'),
                  ),
                  Chip(
                    avatar: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900,
                        child: const Text('JL')),
                    label: const Text('Laurens'),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use wrap. But when i put inside singlechildscrollview, in case child count increases, then it is no more aligned to center.

Comment: inside the column?

Answer (score 1):

You can try wrap like what yeasin sheikh suggested and add alignment to it

```dart
Wrap(
  alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
  crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
  children: [
    //All children widget here
  ]
)
```